# Gradle download and build a full project

Tags: java, gradle, liferay

Gradle is used mainly for dependency management.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to use Gradle to download and install a fully working environment.

For example, is it possible to use Gradle to download Liferay 7, starting a tomcat server, and initializing an out of the box database?

I know there are a lot of setting for a tomcat, for a DB etc... however, all those products are coming with some basic configuration to bootstrap development.

Can it be used in such a way?

Comment: Yes, it probably can. I just wonder what you’d expect as an acceptable answer – probably not a full-fledged build script that creates this setup for you, right?

Comment: Imagine for a moment that your team is working always with the same product with the same configuration pattern. You always use mysql, and you always use elastic search and always use liferay or any other framework. What my question is... Can I provide my team a grade build script that automatically download , install and configure the environment?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I also understood from your question and I believe such a Gradle build script could be created. I was merely wondering what exact answer you are expected here on SO; it’s unlikely that somebody will sit down and write the Gradle script for you. Hence, what would you consider as an acceptable answer? Just some pointers to relevant Gradle plugins that could be helpful? IMHO, your question in its current form is too broad. You should rather split the problem into smaller chunks and ask more specific questions for these chunks.

Comment: I didn't try if "Yes" is accepted by Stackoverflow, or if it's considered too short. But the way this question is phrased, it would be a proper (just not very insightful) answer. However, as @Chriki says above, it's unlikely that someone will write the script as a part of this answer. And in case OEH rephrases the question to ask for such a script, it would be [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow, IMHO.

Comment: Hi, I understand my question is too wide sorry about that. What I was hoping is that some of you will come out with "hey look what you are looking for already exists and it made by 'ycz' And it is called by the community 'xyz"' I was thinking that it might be somewhere on the web someone who is sharing perfectly working grade builds for a full working environment.

Comment: Well, even if it already exists, I'd expect major customization to be required - every single environment is different. In Policy, included Plugins, assumed network-infrastructure (proxies), allowed access (node in enterprise environments anyone?) etc.

Comment: I was thinking more for a local environment. Something to speed up development

Comment: I would say you could try docker, this seems more like what you are looking for. Something like: https://github.com/E-SYSTEMS-TECH/docker-examples-liferay